# Redirect all requests in ExpressJS except the main index page?

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm hosting an ExpressJS/AngularJS site on Heroku, and I'm using Express to redirect all non-https requests to the https version.

My problem is- I don't want to redirect the Home page- everything else, yes. I want to just serve the home page without an https redirect. Any ideas how to do this with Express?

Many thanks!

```
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){
    if( req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https' )
        res.redirect('https://mydomain.com'+req.url)
    else
        next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  if(req.path === '/'){
    next();
  } else if(req.secure){
    next();
  } else {
    var port = 443;  // or load from config
    if(port != 443){
      res.redirect('https://'+req.host+':'+port+req.originalUrl);
      console.log('redirecting to https://'+req.host+':'+port+req.originalUrl);
    } else {
      res.redirect('https://'+req.host+req.originalUrl);
      console.log('redirecting to https://'+req.host+req.originalUrl);
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Whoa! Awesome dude. Let me think through this one. Very nice.

Comment: Put it above all other routes, because express prioritizes routes in the order that you call `app.get()` etc

Comment: Oh whoops I just realized I did `app.get()`, i am editing it to `app.all()` so it works for e.g. POST

Answer (score 0):

```
if (process.env.DEVMODE == 'dev'){
    if( req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https' )
        if !(req.url == homeURL)
           res.redirect('https://mydomain.com'+req.url)
    else
        next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
  } else {
        next();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Monshaw. How would you define homeURL? That's the part I'm having trouble with. Cheers

Comment: you mean your home url, heroku home url, or home urls in general?

Comment: I think Plato's "if req.path === '/' " answered my question. I was using req.url instead of req.path. Thank you!